Password History - Storage - System Design Preventing Reuse or Similar Passwords
I am currently working on a project where I would like to make sure that users do not reuse their recent passwords; are too similar to their current password (i.e. just tacking a number or symbol such as a '!' to the end of the password.
I have seen websites and applications that have enforced these rules. While I can see how to test for reuse of passwords by keeping a table of the hashes for comparison, how do systems enforce the not being similar test without having to store the passwords in plain text in the database?
Your guidance would be gratefully appreciated.

You would need to kind of brute force it, I think.
Take the inputted password, throw it in a loop that adds adds an extra character at the end, beginning, wherever, and then match it against the stored hash.
To give you an idea, you can look at the John The Ripper single crack mode and custom rules.
